# Ignore Empty Inputs when inserting data using a PHP form

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be having an issue with PHP Contact Form. In my form, the only field that is NOT required to be filled up, is the Phone Number. When I fill out the form with the phone number, the data gets inserted into the database, but when I leave that input blank, it doesn't work. It shows me the "success" page but no data is inserted. Is there anyway for the cf.inc.php to ignore the Phone Number field if its empty?

I have added the HTML Form, cf.inc.php and the table structure below.

HTML FORM

```
<form class="contact-form" action="includes/cf.inc.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" required="true" name="cf_name" placeholder="Name*"><br>
  <input type="email" autocomplete="off" required="true" name="cf_email" placeholder="Email*"><br>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="cf_phone" placeholder="Phone Number (Optional)"><br>
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" required="true" name="cf_subject" placeholder="Subject*"><br>
  <textarea name="cf_message" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Write your message in 200 Words*" required="true"></textarea><br>
  <div class="h-project-button">
    <button class="uni-button" type="submit" value="cf_submit" name="cf_submit"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

cf.inc.php

```
<?php
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cf_name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cf_email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cf_phone']);
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cf_subject']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cf_message']);


if (isset($_POST['cf_submit'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contactform (cf_time, cf_name, cf_email, cf_phone, cf_subject, cf_message)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('./contactformfail'); </script>";
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssss", $timestamp, $name, $email, $phone, $subject, $message);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('./contactformsuccess'); </script>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<script> window.location.assign('./contactformfail'); </script>";
}
```

Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `contactform` (
  `cf_id` int NOT NULL,
  `cf_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `cf_email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `cf_phone` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `cf_subject` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `cf_message` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `cf_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: When you're using prepared statements and `bind_param` you should *not* escape the data first. That will cause the escape characters to be stored literally.

Comment: does that mean I should remove the "mysqli_real_escape_string" from my prepared statements at the top? @Barmar

Comment: @RiggsFolly He is using prepared statements. Calm your comments without considering the context. Saying that escaping inputs means that you are not safe are also FUD; it will depend on context as well.

Comment: ___Small Point___ Phone numbers are not integers `cf_phone` should probably be a string

Comment: @EmonHoque Yes, you don't need them. They're not related to the problem, though; see my answer.

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @Barmar if you don't mind, could you tell me a little more about why I dont need to escape the data first when using prepared statements and bind_param? Or guide me to resources where i could learn more about it? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Because that's what prepared statements and `bind_param` do automatically. They ensure that the parameters are substituted securely exactly as provided. If you escape the data, you're adding backslash characters, and these will be stored in the databae.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store the phone number as `INT`. Even though we call it a "number", it's not really one, and converting it to an integer can cause problems. In this case, the problem is that converting an empty string to an integer may be causing an error. Also, phone numbers are often written with punctuation and spaces; converting to an integer will only parse up to the punctuation and ignore the rest.

You should declare it as `VARCHAR`.

You also should check whether `mysqli_stmt_execute()` succeeds. Error checking would have told you why the `INSERT` was failing.

Comment: I have declared  `cf_phone`  varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, and it works as intended! Thankyou! I will select your answer as the correct answer as soon as I am able to!